How Does Frequency Change With Damping (Underdamped Harmonic Oscillators)
I'm studying harmonic oscillators and I'm trying to model a system where both the frequency and amplitude decay over time. This is throwing me off because frequency decay is much less intuitive than amplitude decay for me. I'm honestly not sure how the frequency behaves in an underdamped system, much less how to model an underdamped system with/without the presence of frequency decay.
So my question is how exactly does frequency change with damping in an underdamped system? Is the frequency constant? Does it decay over time?
I'm going to try to answer my own question here purely from my own deduction:
I understand that for an underdamped harmonic oscillator with an equation of the form $ \ddot{x} + 2{\gamma}{\dot{x}} + {{\omega}_o}^2x = 0$, we get the general solution $$ x(t) = Ae^{-{\gamma}t}cos({\omega}_dt + \phi) $$ where $ {\omega}_d  = \sqrt{{{\omega}_o}^2 - {\gamma}^2}$.
So at first glance it looks like the damped frequency is constant (since $ {\gamma} $ and $ {\omega}_o $ appear to be constants). But there clearly is a change in frequency since $ {\omega}_o $ turns to $ {\omega}_d$. My intuition tells me that $ {\gamma} $ should not be constant, so for $ \gamma = 0 $ you would get $ {\omega}_d = {\omega}_o $ and a decaying frequency from there. $ \gamma = {c \over 2m} $, meaning that for a damped frequency we need $ c(t) $.
So for an underdamped harmonic oscillator with both frequency and amplitude damping, we need $$ \ddot{x} + 2{c(t) \over m}{\dot{x}} + {{\omega}_o}^2x = 0$$
Did I get this right?

It is not clear what you are trying to ask. The frequency does not change in time; only the amplitude does. What do you mean by "$\gamma$ should not be constant"?

The frequency does not change in time in a linear system. It might in a nonlinear system.

The answer depends on the physical system you are modeling. For a damped simple harmonic oscillation the answer is no. $\gamma$ is constant.
Now if you do make $c(t)$ non constant, if the temporal variations a slow enough, you can use a complex frequency:
$$ \omega(t) = \omega_d(t) + i\gamma(t) 
$$
with the condition that its magnitude is constant:
$$|\omega(t)|^2 = \omega_d^2(t) + \gamma^2(t)^2 = \omega_0^2 $$
which means you can write it as:
$$\omega(t) = \omega_0e^{i\phi(t)} $$
and use the linear solution with the phase factor slowly changing, but how it changes with time will require some work.
If $c(t)$ changes quickly, then you just have a difficult differential equation to solve.
Maybe Fourier transform to the frequency domain an see what happens (though the prduct $c(t)\dot x(t)$ will be a convolution in the frequency domain--but $\dot x(t)$ should be a narrow function of frequency, which may provide some simplifying approximations (which should be equivalent to the original time domain simplification)).

Thanks for the explanation. I'm sure that I was not expected to do a Fourier transform for this problem so I'll try to take a different approach.

Incidentally, could you explain how ${\omega}_o $ turns into ${\omega}_d$ if $ \gamma $ remains constant?

@JeremyKievit well, it's closed. So read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator You write the solution as $e^{ift}$ ($f$ is angular frequnecy), so at FT turns the differential eq into an algebraic eq: $(f^2 +2\gamma \omega_0 + \omega^2_0)=0$ From there, apply quadratic formula and pick the decreasing solution. This is the most useful problem in physics and engineering.
